# Hide GLUT window

Tags: opengl, glut

Is it possible to hide OpenGL window and the rendering are still running? I use glutHideWindow which will never trigger display function.

If that is not possible, is it possible in the program to change the focus of the current window? I want to run opengl program but I don't need that window. In fact, I want to use the framebuffer that opengl updates at each frame in another program. But it's always annoying to toggle between the two programs. (They both have window)

Comment: @BЈовић: It has nothing to do with the display callback. And no what OP asks is not possible in a naive way.

Comment: @datenwolf Ok, it does depend on the windowing system. My experience is if you issue window rendering, it may be re-rendered - regardless if a window is covered.

Comment: @BЈовић: We're talking about invisible, i.e. hidden windows here, not windows that have been re-mapped into the visible screen. If you render to a hidden/invisible window the graphics will discard all drawing commands, because they're not reaching the screen anyway.

Comment: @BЈовић: OP's problem has nothing to do with GLUT or any framework used. Your tag addition doesn't add any usefull information as the problem would be the same if native Win32 GDI, X11/GLX or Qt or GTK+ were used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to hide OpenGL window and the rendering are still running?

Yes and No to both parts of the question.

If you hide a window, all the pixels of the window's viewport will fail the pixel ownership test when rendering. So you can't use a hidden window as a drawable for OpenGL to operate on.

What you need is an off-screen drawable to draw to.

The modern variant are *Framebuffer Objects* (FBOs), which you can create on a regular OpenGL context, that might even work on a hidden window. FBOs take some drawable attachments (render buffers, textures) and allow OpenGL to draw to these instead to the window.

An older method are PBuffers, also widely supported, but not as easy to use as FBOs.

Note that if you want to perform off-screen rendering on Linux/X11 the X server must be active, i.e. owning the VT so that the GPU actually processes the commands. So you can't just start an X server "in the background" but have another X server use the display device.

Comment: @BЈовић: Two comments with bad advice from you. Please stop making counterproductive suggestions. OP needs a FBO or a PBuffer. There's no need for shared memory at all (shared memory is a inter process technique, but that's not what OP requires).

Comment: Pixel ownership test failing is the best case.  I could also imagine that making the context current fails, and all OpenGL resources might have to be reloaded into a new context when the window regains visibility.

Comment: @BenVoigt: This scenario is not allowed to happen. Both GLX and Win32 GDI allow to bind the context an invisible (hidden/unmapped/inactive) drawable. Drawing operations on the drawable are undefined, but all OpenGL operations happening not on the drawable will work. For PBuffers GLX specifies a "damaged" condition, which is very much like the damaged state of regular windows, i.e. require a full redraw as the contents are undefined. Also because a single OpenGL context is not tied to a single drawable destroying the drawable will not impair the context itself.

Comment: I'm using FBO and set the rendering to display Function, but if the window is hidden then the display function will never be called!

Comment: @YanLi: Of course the display function will not be called by GLUT if GLUT thinks that it won't produce something visible anyway. You have to use the idle function instead.

Comment: @BЈовић: PLEASE STOP WRITING COMMENTS HERE! You're embarrasing yourself. FBO is not a framework, they are a kind OpenGL object offering off-screen rendering. GLUT is a framework to create a window, OpenGL context etc. What they do is completely different and orthogonal. You can use FBOs together with GLUT just fine. Please, if you don't know what's going on then don't write about it. Geez.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the window, you can use `glutHideWindow()` to go offscreen. Then you still render as nomal and use `glReadPixels` to read back and get buffer to use it later.

Comment: Thank you @Ast Derek. My English is bad :)  I will be more careful next time